# Calculating distance between coordinates and reference point

Tags: r, coordinates, distance

I want to calculate the distance between lat1, lon1 and a reference point (52.92343, 5.04127). I want to this for every row in my dataset, so the distance will be calculated with the reference in every row. That means I will create a new column with the distance in km. I can imagine you will have to use some kind of loop function, but so far I have not figured out how to accomplish this. I think I will have to use the packages `geodist` or `geosphere`, but unfortunately was not successful. How can I calculate these distances?

```
structure(list(Day = c("26", "05", "17", "18", "19", "19"), Month = c("07", 
"08", "08", "08", "08", "08"), Year = c("2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021"), Location.Receiver = c("Den Oever Ijsselmeer", 
"Medemblik Ijsselmeer, gemaal", "Den Oever Ijsselmeer", "Den Oever Ijsselmeer", 
"Den Oever Ijsselmeer", "Den Oever Ijsselmeer"), Transmitter = c("A69-1602-59776", 
"A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59769", 
"A69-1602-59776"), Batch.location = c("Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever"), BatchNr = c(8, 
9, 8, 8, 1, 8), Latitude = c(52.92343, 52.76098, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343), Longitude = c(5.04127, 5.12172, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127), Date = structure(c(18834, 18844, 
18856, 18857, 18858, 18858), class = "Date")), row.names = c(1095729L, 
1180267L, 1072657L, 1092667L, 716601L, 1077415L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your `dput()` output is incomplete

Comment: Fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`points_in_circle()` returns the points within a given `radius` from a reference point. The following returns all points within 1000km from the reference point:

```r
library(spatialrisk)
points_in_circle(df, lat_center = 52.92343, lon_center = 5.04127, 
                 lon = Longitude, lat = Latitude, radius = 1e6)
#>         Day Month Year            Location.Receiver    Transmitter
#> 1095729  26    07 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59776
#> 1072657  17    08 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59776
#> 1092667  18    08 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59776
#> 716601   19    08 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59769
#> 1077415  19    08 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59776
#> 1180267  05    08 2021 Medemblik Ijsselmeer, gemaal A69-1602-59777
#>         Batch.location BatchNr Latitude Longitude       Date distance_m
#> 1095729      Den Oever       8 52.92343   5.04127 2021-07-26       0.00
#> 1072657      Den Oever       8 52.92343   5.04127 2021-08-17       0.00
#> 1092667      Den Oever       8 52.92343   5.04127 2021-08-18       0.00
#> 716601       Den Oever       1 52.92343   5.04127 2021-08-19       0.00
#> 1077415      Den Oever       8 52.92343   5.04127 2021-08-19       0.00
#> 1180267      Den Oever       9 52.76098   5.12172 2021-08-05   18875.55
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Great! this works out for me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop, you can just calculate the distance between entries in an array of coordinates in `x` and a single point in `y` using `geodist`. Just passing in the coordinates as lon/lat explicitly and saving back as a numeric vector to `Distance` rather than as the original matrix output.

```r
library(geodist)

df$Distance <- as.numeric(geodist(df[,9:8], c(5.04127, 52.92343)))
#> object has no named columns; assuming order is lon then lat

df$Distance
#> [1]     0.00 18843.92     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find an alternative solution (cf reprex below) using the `sf` and `units` libraries

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(sf)
library(units)

# Convert the df into 'sf' object
df_sf <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

# Create the reference 'sf' object
ref_point_sf <- st_point(c(5.04127, 52.92343)) %>% 
  st_coordinates() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 4326)

# Compute the distance between the reference point and points from 'df_sf'
results <- st_distance(ref_point_sf, df_sf) %>% 
  set_units("km")
```

- Output

```r
results
#> Units: [km]
#>      [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    0 18.85446    0    0    0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**AS A FOLLOW-UP TO YOUR COMMENT**

- Code

```r
library(sf)
library(units)
library(dplyr)


# Convert df into 'sf' object
df_sf <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

# Create the reference 'sf' object
ref_point_sf <- st_point(c(5.04127, 52.92343)) %>% 
  st_coordinates() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 4326)

# Compute the distance between the reference point and points from 'df_sf'
results <- st_distance(df_sf, ref_point_sf) %>% 
  set_units("km") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  drop_units() %>% 
  `colnames<-`(., "dist_km")

# Add 'results' in the original dataframe
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(dist_km = results)
```

- Output

```r
df
#>         Day Month Year            Location.Receiver    Transmitter
#> 1095729  26    07 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59776
#> 1180267  05    08 2021 Medemblik Ijsselmeer, gemaal A69-1602-59777
#> 1072657  17    08 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59776
#> 1092667  18    08 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59776
#> 716601   19    08 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59769
#> 1077415  19    08 2021         Den Oever Ijsselmeer A69-1602-59776
#>         Batch.location BatchNr Latitude Longitude       Date  dist_km
#> 1095729      Den Oever       8 52.92343   5.04127 2021-07-26  0.00000
#> 1180267      Den Oever       9 52.76098   5.12172 2021-08-05 18.85446
#> 1072657      Den Oever       8 52.92343   5.04127 2021-08-17  0.00000
#> 1092667      Den Oever       8 52.92343   5.04127 2021-08-18  0.00000
#> 716601       Den Oever       1 52.92343   5.04127 2021-08-19  0.00000
#> 1077415      Den Oever       8 52.92343   5.04127 2021-08-19  0.00000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I have applied your code to my script and it seems to work. However, as I understand it correctly, the value `results` is now 1 row, with 2525 units. I want an extra column in my original dataset with the calculated distance you put in `results`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi @Pepijn Vermeiren, please find above my edit to answer your comment. Hope that this is what you were looking for. Cheers.

Comment: absolutely amazing, exactly how I want it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback @Pepijn95. Glad that I could help you. Please consider marking this answer as "accepted" to make it easier for other SO users to find the right answer. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.